# How can I get CoreLocation to resume ranging when the device is restarted?

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I was able to get the monitoring and ranging to work when I backgrounded the app. However when I restarted my phone, I'm able to get didDetermineState, ranging, and monitoring ONLY when the lock screen is on. When I go into the home screen or the phone screen is off, the CoreLocation functions (state change, ranging and monitoring) is paused. How can I make resume didDetermineState, didRangeBeacons, didMonitorBeacons when I go into the home screen or the phone screen is off? Because when I entered into my app and backgrounded it, even when the phone screen is off or the lock screen is on, I'm able to get the corelocation updates. Why would restarting the phone be different?